# Python sin and cosine giving incorrect values

Tags: python, math, pygame, trigonometry

I have code that draws a line from 2 points; One on the middle bottom of the screen, and the other to the mouse pointer. I am trying to constrain the point by not exceeding a **length** parameter that I set. Heres the code:

```
import pygame
import Resources as r
import math as m

pygame.init()

class Segment():



    def __init__(self, _screen, _id, _start_pos, _length):
        self.screen = _screen
        self.id = _id
        self.start_pos = _start_pos
        self.length = _length

    def update(self):
        if self.id == 1:
            mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()


            self.angle = m.atan2(mouse_pos[1]-self.start_pos[1],mouse_pos[0]-self.start_pos[0])
            self.a = self.start_pos
            self.b = (m.cos(self.angle)*self.length, m.sin(self.angle)*self.length)


            self.draw_line(self.a, self.b, r.black, 4)




    def draw_line(self, start, end, color, width):
        if self.id == 1:
            pygame.draw.line(self.screen, color, start, end, width)

    def get_data(self):
        return (self.start_pos, self.end_)
```

I am seeing very different results when I run this that I would expect, it doesnt line up with my mouse and often just oscillates back and forth when the mouse is moved.

Comment: use button `{}` to correctly format code

Comment: probably you could do this with [pygame.math.Vector2d](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html)

Comment: You used tabs for indentation, which is not a good idea in Python. Convert each tab to 4 spaces, copy-and-paste into the question editor, highlight the code, then click the `{}` button to show the editor that it is code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.b` is calculated based on origin 0, 0, not `self.start_pos`.

Add coordinates in `self.a` to `self.b`.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** as skrx pointed out in comment: mouse position doesn't have to be converted to `Vector2` because `tuple-Vector2` gives `Vector2`.

---

You can do the same with `python.math.Vector2`

Your `start` point on the middle bottom of the screen

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

start = pygame.math.Vector2(screen_rect.centerx, screen_rect.bottom)
```

And `end` point using mouse positon and length

```
#mouse = pygame.math.Vector2(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) # edited
mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
end = start + (mouse - start).normalize() * length
```

And now you can draw

```
pygame.draw.line(screen, (255,0,0), start, end)
```

---

Working example

```
import pygame

# === CONSTANS === (UPPER_CASE names)

BLACK = (  0,   0,   0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

RED   = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN = (  0, 255,   0)
BLUE  = (  0,   0, 255)

SCREEN_WIDTH  = 600
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 400

# === MAIN === (lower_case names)

# --- init ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()

# --- objects ---

start = pygame.math.Vector2(screen_rect.centerx, screen_rect.bottom)
end = start
length = 150

# --- mainloop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
is_running = True

while is_running:

    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        # --- global events ---

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            is_running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                is_running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            #mouse = pygame.math.Vector2(pygame.mouse.get_pos()) # edited
            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            end = start + (mouse - start).normalize() * length

        # --- objects events ---

            # empty

    # --- updates ---

        # empty

    # --- draws ---

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    pygame.draw.line(screen, RED, start, end)

    pygame.display.update()

    # --- FPS ---

    clock.tick(25)

# --- the end ---

pygame.quit()
```

Red line has always the same length and it shows direction to cursor. 
[image]

Comment: A little tip: You don't have to turn the mouse pos into a vector, since `start` is already a vector and you can just subtract it from a tuple as well (the result will be another `Vector2`).